# Quick numpy array extension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wonder if there is a trick to extending a numpy array with consecutive
numbers in between each original values, up to a user controlled default length. Perhaps there is already a built-in function that turns x into y

```
x=np.array([4,8,4,10])

y=np.array([4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,4,5,6,7,10,11,12,13])
```

Here the length between each element that I added was three. Speed is of the essence here. I need something like this for my column data to work in creating a sparse
matrix.

Also, if I have an array such as

```
s=np.array([0,1])
```

is there a quick way to extend each element an arbitrary amount of
times, lets say 4 for example:

```
s=np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1])
```

Comment: For the second half of your question, have a look at numpy.repeat or numpy.tile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadcasted addition is probably the fastest

```
In [241]: (x[:,None]+np.arange(4)).ravel()
Out[241]: array([ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  4,  5,  6,  7, 10, 11, 12, 13])
```

It gets trickier if adding different amounts for each sublist.

`repeat` is useful:

```
In [242]: np.repeat(np.array([0,1]),[3,4])
Out[242]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

`tile` is another good tool.

Comment: All great methods guys, this one was fastest though. Mahalo!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a built-in function that does precisely that, but with some creativity you could do:

```
>>> x=np.array([4,8,4,10])
>>> np.array([x+i for i in range(4)]).T.ravel()
array([ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  4,  5,  6,  7, 10, 11, 12, 13])
```

For the second half of your question, have a look at [`numpy.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy.repeat) and [`numpy.tile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html#numpy.tile).

Answer (score 0):

This works on lists:

```
def extend(myList, n):
    extensions = [range(x, x + n) for x in myList]
    return [item for sublist in extensions for item in sublist] # flatten
```

Use as follows:

```
extend([4, 8, 4, 10], 4)
```